# Exempting "of" and other similar strings in title('string') in QGIS expression based labelling?

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I have a field name where all the values are capitalized so I used title('string') to get my desired results:

```
 'OLONGAPO CITY'
```

will result to

```
 'Olongapo City'.
```

However, there are strings such as:

```
 CITY OF MAKATI
```

I want it to appear as

```
'City of Makati'
```

instead of

```
'City Of Makati'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using something like the following expression:

```
replace(title("fieldName"), 'Of', 'of')
```

Comment: Great that was quick!

Comment: @brentiemapper - Most welcome, glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want proper title case rules (including correct handling of a/of/the/etc), you could grab the source of Titlecase.py (See https://muffinresearch.co.uk/titlecasepy-titlecase-in-python/ ) and insert this in a custom expression function from the "Function Editor" tab in the expression builder:

[image]

The code look something like:

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='String')
def title_case(value1, feature, parent):
    return titlecase(value1)
```

...followed by the entire copy/pasted contents of [`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ppannuto/python-titlecase/master/titlecase/__init__.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ppannuto/python-titlecase/master/titlecase/__init__.py)

You'll then be able to use this new `title_case` function anywhere in QGIS expressions:[image]